# Convert Negative Sobel Gradient Values into 0 to 6.28 Ranges

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction, sobel

I've tried to create an Image Processing Program with Twelve Directional Feature Extraction (from this url source https://www.ijcaonline.org/journal/number3/pxc387173.pdf)

I used this code to get the gradient result

```
def sobel(citra_thresh):
h, w = citra_thresh.shape
# define filters
horizontal = np.array([[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 0, 2], [-1, 0, 1]]) 
vertical = np.array([[-1, -2, -1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1]]) 
newhorizontalImage = np.zeros((h, w))
newverticalImage = np.zeros((h, w))
newgradientImage = np.zeros((h, w))
newdirectionImage = np.zeros((h,w))

for i in range(1, h - 1):
    for j in range(1, w - 1):
        horizontalGrad = (horizontal[0, 0] * citra_thresh[i - 1, j - 1]) + \
                         (horizontal[0, 1] * citra_thresh[i - 1, j]) + \
                         (horizontal[0, 2] * citra_thresh[i - 1, j + 1]) + \
                         (horizontal[1, 0] * citra_thresh[i, j - 1]) + \
                         (horizontal[1, 1] * citra_thresh[i, j]) + \
                         (horizontal[1, 2] * citra_thresh[i, j + 1]) + \
                         (horizontal[2, 0] * citra_thresh[i + 1, j - 1]) + \
                         (horizontal[2, 1] * citra_thresh[i + 1, j]) + \
                         (horizontal[2, 2] * citra_thresh[i + 1, j + 1])

        #if (horizontalGrad == 0):
         #   horizontalGrad = 0.0001
        newhorizontalImage[i - 1, j - 1] = abs(horizontalGrad)
        verticalGrad = (vertical[0, 0] * citra_thresh[i - 1, j - 1]) + \
                       (vertical[0, 1] * citra_thresh[i - 1, j]) + \
                       (vertical[0, 2] * citra_thresh[i - 1, j + 1]) + \
                       (vertical[1, 0] * citra_thresh[i, j - 1]) + \
                       (vertical[1, 1] * citra_thresh[i, j]) + \
                       (vertical[1, 2] * citra_thresh[i, j + 1]) + \
                       (vertical[2, 0] * citra_thresh[i + 1, j - 1]) + \
                       (vertical[2, 1] * citra_thresh[i + 1, j]) + \
                       (vertical[2, 2] * citra_thresh[i + 1, j + 1])
        newverticalImage[i - 1, j - 1] = abs(verticalGrad)
        mag = np.sqrt(pow(horizontalGrad, 2.0) + pow(verticalGrad, 2.0))
        newgradientImage[i - 1, j - 1] = mag
        newgradientImage = newgradientImage.astype(np.int)

        direct = np.arctan2((verticalGrad),(horizontalGrad))
        #tes=(horizontalGrad/verticalGrad)
        #direct = (np.arctan(tes))
        newdirectionImage[i - 1, j - 1] = direct
        #newdirectionImage = newdirectionImage.astype(np.float)
        newdirectionImage = np.around(newdirectionImage,decimals=2)
return newdirectionImage
```

I tried to get the gradient for this image

[image: C]

And I got this result

[image: result]

The journal expected that the gradient values should be ranging between 0 to 6.28.

But I got the negative values gradient. How do I convert them into 0 to 6.28 range?

Comment: Just a wild guess from your value range: Do you possibly get values `-3.14 ... 3.14` (-pi ... pi)? So, maybe just add `3.14` (pi) to all values to get values `0.00 ... 6.28` (0 ... 2 * pi)!?

Comment: i never got values bigger than 3.14 .. But if i do that, the black pixels gonna have 3.14 values, not 0 anymore. I dont know whether its okey or no to use that trick to the method shown in the journal, anw thanks for your respond :)

Comment: `atan2` produces values in the range -π to π. In the linked article they compute an angle between 0 and 2π (they call it `grad`). As @HansHirse said, you can add π to your angle to match the article's angle. The alternative is to add 2π to the negative values only. Note that the article doesn't use the magnitude, only the angle.